# Linux C programming memory full address sanitizer error

Tags: c, memory-management

I am still quite new to C programming. Working on a school project. When I run my program, I do not get the right output and this is displayed.

```
==118431== WARNING: AddressSanitizer failed to allocate 0xfffffffc00000000 bytes
```

Obviously, I can tell that there is not enough memory that needs to be allocated. My question is, by freeing up memory in the program, will this help solve this issue? Or do I have to work on the implementation of my program

Comment: Share the minimal piece of code that produces this error - it will allow people to assist you better, and you may find the error yourself in the process.

Comment: That's quite a large amount of memory to try and allocate, not even todays big-iron system have that amount of memory available. So what are you really trying to do? What is your program doing? Can you please try to create an [mcve] and show us?

Comment: I cant really post code as its rather long. My project deals with circuits and outputting truth tables for as many as 20 inputs, so I imagine it has to do with not freeing memory

Comment: Then try to isolate the part that is causing this problem, turn it into a standalone example and post that. If we can't see the code, there's not much we can do about it.

Comment: I was just hoping to find out whether this was an implementation issue or that I wasn't freeing memory but I know its an implementation issue now so thank you!

Comment: so I ran GDB and am getting this, I set a breakpoint on main and stepped through the next few lines until... (gdb) n
__libc_start_main (main=0x400d1d <main>, argc=1, ubp_av=0x7fffffffd898, 
    init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, 
    stack_end=0x7fffffffd888) at ../csu/libc-start.c:308
308   exit (result);

Comment: Was that the only error line or was there more? I know certain kernel versions had changes that broke asan ([example](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=869090)), wondering if it could be related.